# error while opening virtual machine. vmx file is corrupt

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have installed an operating system on my virtual machine. However, my pc didnt shut down correctly at a time. After the incident i could not boot my operating system within vmware. When i checked my `vmx` file, i discovered this line of code was missing `smc.version = “0”`

Upon adding it, it causes an error saying the vmx file is corrupt. Is there a way t can make it work? Do i need to recreate another `vmx` file?

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "12"
numvcpus = "2"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
sata0.present = "TRUE"
memsize = "7644"
sata0:0.present = "TRUE"
sata0:0.fileName = "C:\MAC OS\macOS High Sierra Final\macOS High Sierra Final.vmdk"
sata0:1.present = "TRUE"
sata0:1.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "hostonly"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "34"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
smc.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
ich7m.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "TRUE"
board-id.reflectHost = "TRUE"
firmware = "efi"
displayName = "macOS 10.13"
guestOS = "darwin16-64"
nvram = "macOS 10.13.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
gui.exitOnCLIHLT = "TRUE"
powerType.powerOff = "soft"
powerType.powerOn = "soft"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
powerType.reset = "soft"
extendedConfigFile = "macOS 10.13.vmxf"
smc.version = "0"
numa.autosize.vcpu.maxPerVirtualNode = "2"
numa.autosize.cookie = "20001"
uuid.bios = "56 4d da 6b bb 9d 01 26-8e 2d e4 4b 8e 51 cf 2d"
uuid.location = "56 4d da 6b bb 9d 01 26-8e 2d e4 4b 8e 51 cf 2d"
migrate.hostlog = ".\macOS 10.13-2c4fd680.hlog"
sata0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "33"
usb_xhci.pciSlotNumber = "-1"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "35"
sata0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0C:29:51:CF:2D"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "-1907241171"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "42"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "134217728"
vmotion.checkpointSVGAPrimarySize = "134217728"
cleanShutdown = "TRUE"
softPowerOff = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:6.speed = "2"
usb_xhci:6.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:6.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:6.port = "6"
usb_xhci:6.parent = "-1"
usb_xhci:7.speed = "4"
usb_xhci:7.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:7.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:7.port = "7"
usb_xhci:7.parent = "-1"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "198"
sata0:1.fileName = "auto detect"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
toolsInstallManager.lastInstallError = "21004"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.present = "true"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "true"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "true"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "true"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "C:\Users\bnotion\Desktop\Shared Folder MAC"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "Shared Folder MAC"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
ethernet1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet1.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet1.virtualDev = "e1000e"
ethernet1.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet1.addressType = "generated"
ethernet1.pciSlotNumber = "224"
ethernet1.generatedAddress = "00:0C:29:51:CF:37"
ethernet1.generatedAddressOffset = "10"
mks.keyboardFilter = "allow"
workingDir = "."
tools.upgrade.policy = "upgradeAtPowerCycle"
svga.vramSize = "134217728"
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
usb_xhci:4.port = "4"
usb_xhci:4.parent = "-1"
usb:1.speed = "2"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
sata0:1.autodetect = "TRUE"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:0.deviceType = "hid"
usb:0.port = "0"
usb:0.parent = "-1"
smc.version = “0”
```

Answer (score 3):

`smc.version = "0"` is in the file twice.  The real original entry is directly under the line:

```
extendedConfigFile = "macOS 10.13.vmxf"
```

Delete the last line of the file. It may not be the only problem, but it will help.